# Fetching console log response for every select option tag using python and selenium

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, google-chrome, testing

So basically as the title says I'm trying to fetch log response for every option
from select tag and display those logs. When I try this approach using selenium with python
I only getfirst two logs for the first 2 options..

```
selects = driver.find_element_by_name("documentType")
selecting = Select(selects)
##### FIRST OPTION
selecting.select_by_index(0)
data = driver.get_log('browser')
time.sleep(2)
print(data)
####SECOND OPTION
selecting.select_by_index(1)
data = driver.get_log('browser')
time.sleep(2)
print(data)
###THIRD OPTION
selecting.select_by_index(2)
data = driver.get_log('browser')
time.sleep(2)
print(data)
```

My question is why am I getting logs for the first two options but not for the third.
How can I overcome this issue because when I switch the order let'say I select second option
primarly and then the third and the first option ,it would log only second and the third option, but
not the first one.

Comment: What are you getting from the first two?  'browser' logs are really just the console log from chrome.

Comment: Ok this is the output I'm getting. You can clearly see that 3.rd option is an empty array but should actually be log there. https://prnt.sc/vgdnlr

Comment: Ok, so this makes more sense. You have console errors on the first two but not the third select.  My guess is there isn't anything to log on the third because it's working.

Comment: Ty for ur response. But the problem is when I switch the order let's say I want first to log third option, second, and then the first option. The first option will be empty array

Comment: So you mean that you `select_by_index(2)`, then `select_by_index(1)` etc...?  and when you do that 2 and 1 results in an logged response, but 0 doesn't?

Comment: yea, that's exactly what I'm currently facing

Comment: I'd say you're catching a javascript bug on the page. If you look at the error it says bootstrap.min.js tooltips requires Tether.  Perhaps it's only trying a couple times then gives up?  Are there supposed to be tooltips on the select options?  And when you make the selection it's trying but failing to call those tooltips?

Comment: It should only display error for the first option, I think that get_log stops after a few tries but nevermind I just have to find another way of logging console output. Ty for ur time

Comment: The console is continually logging messages to a buffer; `get_log` will return all of the messages in the buffer since the last call to `get_log`.  Each call will clear the buffer.

Comment: Something else to keep in mind, console messages are not always in sync with your actions in selenium.  There can and often is a small delay between your actions and the logged messages to the console. Is it possible that second error message is actually occurring from the first selection?  a good way to test this would be to wait longer between selections.

Comment: I'm using time.sleep(10) between the calls

Comment: And I've made a little test now with the more options and it's still giving only output for the first 2 options.

Comment: did the two messages occur after the first, but before the second?